# setOnClickListener throwing null pointer exception while data from main activity is replaced into a new activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

Here is the code for it
The problem has started when i tried to add a splash screen to my application.
I've shifted all the data in main activity to a new activity and made some required changes.
The error i got was

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplicationtest.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:130)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7820)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7809)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1318)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3527) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)




package com.example.myapplicationtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.View;

import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9;
    TextView B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9;
    TextView C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9;
    TextView D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9;
    TextView E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9;
    TextView F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9;
    TextView G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9;
    TextView H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9;
    TextView I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9;
    Button b_solve,b_reset,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0;

    public int arr[][]=new int[9][9];



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        A1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a1);
        A2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
        A3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a3);
        A4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a4);
        A5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a5);
        A6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a6);
        A7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a7);
        A8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a8);
        A9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a9);
        B1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        B2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        B3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        B4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b4);
        B5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b5);
        B6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b6);
        B7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b7);
        B8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b8);
        B9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b9);
        C1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c1);
        C2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c2);
        C3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c3);
        C4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c4);
        C5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c5);
        C6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c6);
        C7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c7);
        C8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c8);
        C9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c9);
        D1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d1);
        D2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d2);
        D3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d3);
        D4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d4);
        D5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d5);
        D6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d6);
        D7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d7);
        D8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d8);
        D9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d9);
        E1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        E2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e2);
        E3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e3);
        E4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e4);
        E5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e5);
        E6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e6);
        E7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e7);
        E8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e8);
        E9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e9);
        F1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        F2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        F3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f3);
        F4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f4);
        F5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f5);
        F6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f6);
        F7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f7);
        F8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f8);
        F9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f9);
        G1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g1);
        G2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g2);
        G3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g3);
        G4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g4);
        G5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g5);
        G6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g6);
        G7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g7);
        G8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g8);
        G9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g9);
        H1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h1);
        H2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h2);
        H3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h3);
        H4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h4);
        H5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h5);
        H6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h6);
        H7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h7);
        H8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h8);
        H9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h9);
        I1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i1);
        I2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i2);
        I3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i3);
        I4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i4);
        I5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i5);
        I6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i6);
        I7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i7);
        I8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i8);
        I9= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i9);
        b_solve=(Button) findViewById(R.id.solve);
        b_reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
        b0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_0);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_3);
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_4);
        b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_5);
        b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_6);
        b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_7);
        b8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_8);
        b9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_9);
        for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){
                arr[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        A1.setOnClickListener(this);
        A2.setOnClickListener(this);
        A3.setOnClickListener(this);
        A4.setOnClickListener(this);
        A5.setOnClickListener(this);
        A6.setOnClickListener(this);
        A7.setOnClickListener(this);
        A8.setOnClickListener(this);
        A9.setOnClickListener(this);

        B1.setOnClickListener(this);
        B2.setOnClickListener(this);
        B3.setOnClickListener(this);
        B4.setOnClickListener(this);
        B5.setOnClickListener(this);
        B6.setOnClickListener(this);
        B7.setOnClickListener(this);
        B8.setOnClickListener(this);
        B9.setOnClickListener(this);

        C1.setOnClickListener(this);
        C2.setOnClickListener(this);
        C3.setOnClickListener(this);
        C4.setOnClickListener(this);
        C5.setOnClickListener(this);
        C6.setOnClickListener(this);
        C7.setOnClickListener(this);
        C8.setOnClickListener(this);
        C9.setOnClickListener(this);

        D1.setOnClickListener(this);
        D2.setOnClickListener(this);
        D3.setOnClickListener(this);
        D4.setOnClickListener(this);
        D5.setOnClickListener(this);
        D6.setOnClickListener(this);
        D7.setOnClickListener(this);
        D8.setOnClickListener(this);
        D9.setOnClickListener(this);

        E1.setOnClickListener(this);
        E2.setOnClickListener(this);
        E3.setOnClickListener(this);
        E4.setOnClickListener(this);
        E5.setOnClickListener(this);
        E6.setOnClickListener(this);
        E7.setOnClickListener(this);
        E8.setOnClickListener(this);
        E9.setOnClickListener(this);

        F1.setOnClickListener(this);
        F2.setOnClickListener(this);
        F3.setOnClickListener(this);
        F4.setOnClickListener(this);
        F5.setOnClickListener(this);
        F6.setOnClickListener(this);
        F7.setOnClickListener(this);
        F8.setOnClickListener(this);
        F9.setOnClickListener(this);

        G1.setOnClickListener(this);
        G2.setOnClickListener(this);
        G3.setOnClickListener(this);
        G4.setOnClickListener(this);
        G5.setOnClickListener(this);
        G6.setOnClickListener(this);
        G7.setOnClickListener(this);
        G8.setOnClickListener(this);
        G9.setOnClickListener(this);

        H1.setOnClickListener(this);
        H2.setOnClickListener(this);
        H3.setOnClickListener(this);
        H4.setOnClickListener(this);
        H5.setOnClickListener(this);
        H6.setOnClickListener(this);
        H7.setOnClickListener(this);
        H8.setOnClickListener(this);
        H9.setOnClickListener(this);


        I1.setOnClickListener(this);
        I2.setOnClickListener(this);
        I3.setOnClickListener(this);
        I4.setOnClickListener(this);
        I5.setOnClickListener(this);
        I6.setOnClickListener(this);
        I7.setOnClickListener(this);
        I8.setOnClickListener(this);
        I9.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Animation anim1 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.blink_anim);



        b_solve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b_solve.startAnimation(anim1);
                Solver solver=new Solver(arr);
                if(solver.solve()) {
                    arr=solver.solved_sudo();
                    A1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][0]));
                    A2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][1]));
                    A3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][2]));
                    A4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][3]));
                    A5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][4]));
                    A6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][5]));
                    A7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][6]));
                    A8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][7]));
                    A9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[0][8]));
                    B1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][0]));
                    B2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][1]));
                    B3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][2]));
                    B4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][3]));
                    B5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][4]));
                    B6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][5]));
                    B7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][6]));
                    B8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][7]));
                    B9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[1][8]));
                    C1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][0]));
                    C2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][1]));
                    C3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][2]));
                    C4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][3]));
                    C5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][4]));
                    C6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][5]));
                    C7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][6]));
                    C8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][7]));
                    C9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[2][8]));
                    D1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][0]));
                    D2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][1]));
                    D3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][2]));
                    D4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][3]));
                    D5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][4]));
                    D6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][5]));
                    D7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][6]));
                    D8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][7]));
                    D9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[3][8]));
                    E1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][0]));
                    E2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][1]));
                    E3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][2]));
                    E4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][3]));
                    E5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][4]));
                    E6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][5]));
                    E7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][6]));
                    E8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][7]));
                    E9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[4][8]));
                    F1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][0]));
                    F2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][1]));
                    F3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][2]));
                    F4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][3]));
                    F5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][4]));
                    F6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][5]));
                    F7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][6]));
                    F8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][7]));
                    F9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[5][8]));
                    G1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][0]));
                    G2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][1]));
                    G3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][2]));
                    G4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][3]));
                    G5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][4]));
                    G6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][5]));
                    G7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][6]));
                    G8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][7]));
                    G9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[6][8]));
                    H1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][0]));
                    H2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][1]));
                    H3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][2]));
                    H4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][3]));
                    H5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][4]));
                    H6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][5]));
                    H7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][6]));
                    H8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][7]));
                    H9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[7][8]));
                    I1.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][0]));
                    I2.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][1]));
                    I3.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][2]));
                    I4.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][3]));
                    I5.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][4]));
                    I6.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][5]));
                    I7.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][6]));
                    I8.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][7]));
                    I9.setText(Integer.toString(arr[8][8]));

                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Unsolved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

As the remaining code is lengthy,ive uploaded how much is necessary.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which is line 130?

Comment: You'd probably benefit by replacing the 81 `TextView` variables by a single `TextView[9][9]` or `TextView[81]` array. This way you will be able to check for nulls and apply listeners by iterating over elements.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that some view is null, then, when you call setOnClickListener() on a null object you will get a NullPointerException. It could be hard to know which view is null because you have many, but a good way to avoid the Exception could be making safe calls like this

```
if(view != null){
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

That would apply to all your views.